NSApplicationPresentationDisableHideApplication is not disabling the "Hide" option from the dock menu
I am trying to use the following code to disable the Hide option for my application :
    NSApplicationPresentationOptions options = [NSApp presentationOptions];
    options |= NSApplicationPresentationDisableHideApplication;
    [NSApp setPresentationOptions:options];

, but it doesn't have any effect : the Hide option is still clickable :

How could I remove or disable this option?

This question is similar to: How to create a customized dock menu for my macOS application in the dock using Xcode. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
